# Merge and replace table id with name

Tags: mysql, merge

table employee:

```
+----+------------+
| id | firstname  |
+----+------------+
| 1  |   name1    | 
+----+------------+
```

table orders:

```
+----+--------+
| id |  eid   |
+----+--------+
|  1 |   2    |        
+----+--------+
```

Is possible with one query get this result?

```
+----+--------+
| id |  eid   |
+----+--------+
| 1  | name1  |        
+----+--------+
```

Comment: Are you attempting to update the name of the column?  The values in the column?  Just select both columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly do `update` if the datatype of `orders.eid` is int. Change it to sting first then execute this `UPDATE` statement,

```
UPDATE  orders a
        INNER JOIN employee b
            ON a.id = b.id
SET     a.eid = b.firstName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're asking for, but it's not entirely clear from your question.

```
select orders.id, employee.firstname
from orders
inner join employee on orders.eid = employee.id
```